# Oracle db Trigger same row update count

Tags: oracle, triggers

I would like to update the Oracle db using Triggers.

I have 2 columns: `login_count` and `last_login_date_time`.

I want `login_count` to increment by 1 when the `last_login_date_time` is updated by my application.

I have tried:

```
create or replace trigger increment_login_count before update of last_login_date_time
on ct_causer
for each row
begin
  update ct_causer set LOGIN_COUNT = LOGIN_COUNT + 1;
END;
```

But the problem is all the rows are updated to `LOGIN_COUNT + 1`.

Is it possible to just update that particular row where the `last_login_date_time` is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
create or replace trigger increment_login_count 
  before update of last_login_date_time
  on ct_causer
for each row
begin
  :new.login_count := :new.login_count + 1;  
end;
```